# custom Slider Issue in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider

I am recreating a slider with vanilla JS. The issue is that I have searched for `window.scroll()` and `window.scrollBy()` but I didn't understood them. Can anyone can explain in detail their parameters and any other methods to make scroll animation or scroll sliders I will appreciate it.

I am using React. On next button it is only working one time. When I click again it is not working I need help.

I am recreating this [sidebar](https://www.nintendo.com/us/store/products/stardew-valley-switch/) for your reference.

I never have practice regarding the scroll and sliders also refrences will be appreciated thanks

```
const imgDiv = useRef(null);
  let imgChilds;
  useEffect(() => {
    imgChilds = imgDiv.current.children[0].width;
  }, []);

  function nextClick() {
    let slider = imgDiv.current;

    slider.scroll({
      left: 100,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  }
```